# SAP SuccessFactors Recruiting Marketing integrating jobs with external sites

Tags: sap-successfactors

Maybe this question is straightforward for some of you, however, I invested some time searching over the internet about the capability of pulling all posted/published jobs from SAP SuccessFactors Recruiting Marketing through APIs without a clear answer.

One of our clients has its site built on top of the Career Site Builder module in SAP SucessFactors. We are looking to pull all published jobs into and integrate them on an external website? I'm looking for an answer for the following points:

1. Does SAP SuccessFactors provides APIs for Jobs and job search?
2. Where I can find comprehensive documentation about the APIs?
3. If there are APIs to integrate with, what is the mechanism of integration for example Restful APIs calls?
4. If there are no APIs available, has anyone managed to pull the jobs into external sites and apps, and how?

Please note, I have checked [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8477193265ea4172a1dda118505ca631/2111/en-US/6839a997c32f44a4bfc972ec1843d574.html) documentation, but as stated the sync job is used for the internal module Career Site Builder.

Answer (score 0):

lmk if this helps:

1. the "JobRequisition" entity is best used for Jobs and Job search info: https://help.sap.com/viewer/28bc3c8e3f214ab487ec51b1b8709adc/2111/en-US/5511f05d636f414084a22909bc35f509.html
2. These are the most comprehensive docs: https://cloudintegration.us2.hana.ondemand.com/package/SuccessFactorsEmployeeCentral/odata
3. Our team has used their odata/v2 API, which is REST
4. If you find you're still stuck on your use case, then consider checking out Merge's docs — we offer a pretty easy way to pull Jobs from SAP and dozens of other ATS with one straightforward REST API - you can see what info we pull from SAP and how you access it here: https://www.merge.dev/docs/integrations/ats/sap-successfactors

Answer (score 0):

Successfactors jobs are usually available as an XML feed from the successfactors website, in addition to the suggested JobsRequisition REST API as suggested in the other reply. Eg.

```
https://career10.successfactors.com/careers?company=XXXX&career_ns=job_listing_summary&resultType=XML
```

where you supply the company id used, and where you have to replace the career10 hostname prefix for something suitable for your company.